# async No response On the server side, 200ok comes in, but I can't get it

Tags: vue.js

async No response On the server side, 200ok comes in, but I can't get it.

I've tried the watch method, but don't. I want to solve it asynchronously.

```
    async mounted() {
      try{
          let response =await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/process')
          this.msg = response
      }
      catch (err) {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          console.log(err)
      }
    }
};
```

There is no reaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An axios response will contain a number of properties what you are likely looking for is `response.data` try that and you should have your response assuming you are actually getting something. You can always look in the network tab to see exactly what is coming in even if it not showing on your app, just look for the call and see what the response or `preview` show.

In the event that your data is not updating in the template you would need to create a key on the element that needs to update to force a rerender, this is because vue's reactivity only works (or mostly) with primitive values not nested structures.

Comment: Json values ​​are well communicated to the network and preview. However, it does not apply to web pages. Keep the values ​​you had before. Can you see the problem?

Comment: Please understand that I used Google Translator.

Comment: How can I keep the first msg content null?